# In general, why do capacitors have a higher tolerance than resistors?

Tags: resistance, capacitance

In general, why do capacitors have a higher tolerance than resistors? Capacitors have a tolerance of around 10%-40% while resistors have smaller tolerances generally. Why is that?

Comment: Wait till you see inductors...

Comment: I would guess its because the dielectric they use is more expensive to keep in tight tolerances compared to the materials resistors are made of. Just a guess, so I cannot submit this as an answer.

Comment: There are good answers, but: Why boats are slower than airplanes?

Comment: [I am so confused right now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekranoplan).

Answer (score 5):

Capacitor tolerances vary widely depending on the underlying technology.

Resistor tolerances also CAN vary widely if inferior technologies are used, but these have largely been eliminated as not being cost effective or desirable and per-item trimming either mechanically or by LASER can be economic in some cases. 
"Composition" resistors were once common and had perhaps +/- 20% tolerance - worse sometimes. Long gone. Carbon film has tended to be replaced by metal film with better temperature stability and reliability.

You can buy +/- 1% tolerance capacitors, and +100%/-50% tolerance capacitors.

- Electrolytic capacitors that rely on the surface area of an etched electride (eg "wet" aluminum) or a sintered electrode (eg Tantalum bead) depend on a mechanically inexact process to derive surface area and electrolyte thickness, and are accordingly hard to control tightly.
- Certain ceramic capacitors may have wide tolerances because the underlying dielectric properties are not temperature stable.
- Plastic film capacitors can be +/- 5% tolerance and very stable dielectric materials such as polystyrene may allow +/- 1% tolerance capacitors to be offered.

Answer (score 4):

Electrolytic capacitors have **wide** tolerance ranges because of their [construction](http://www.ami.ac.uk/courses/topics/0136_ec/index.html). Chemical etching is used to increase the effective surface area of the aluminum sheets that make up an electrolytic capacitor, but you can't easily predict the actual yield until the capacitor has been completed.